# A question on primes larger than a bound in an arithmetic progression

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization, arithmetic-progressions, prime-gaps, sieve-theory

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ be a semi-prime with unknown factorization, $n = pq$, where $p, q \in \mathbb{P}$, the set of primes. Without loss of generality, let $p \lt q$.

Say we have done trial division and determined that $2, 3, 5, ..., p_{\beta} \in \mathbb{P}$ where $p_{\beta} < \beta$, a smooth bound, do not divide $n$.

If $\exists r,t \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $q = p_{\beta} + rt$ and $q - p_{\beta} \gt p$ then $\exists r \in \mathbb{P}$ by the prime factorization theorem. We know that for sufficiently large $\beta$, $r = 2$ is possible since the difference of primes is even.

**Q1: Is it true that $\exists r > p_{\beta}, r \in \mathbb{P}$?**

**Example:**
Let $q = 73$ and $2, 3, 5, p_{\beta} = 7$. We have $q = 73 = 7 + 11 \times 6$ and $r = 11, t = 6$.

Dirichlet's prime number theorem states that there are infinitely many primes in any arithmetic progression $a + nd$ with $a, d$ coprime.

My question could alternatively be stated as:

**Q2: whether a specific prime greater than $p_{\beta}$ occurs in a *any* arithmetic progression with initial term $p_{\beta}$?** (Edit: @abiessu's comment answers this affirmatively)

The motivation for this question is to build a factoring sieve. After exhausting trial division up to the bound $p_{\beta}$, we want to switch to arithmetic progressions to search for primes up to $\sqrt n$. I suppose there exist effective arithmetic progressions with large $r$ that can yield $p$ or $q$ in very few steps (i.e., small $t$).

Comment: Let $q\gt u=p_{\beta}$, then $q\in (q-u)x+u$ as an arithmetic progression...

Comment: @abiessu: Thanks. That answers the question that $q$ appears in an AP with initial term $p_{\beta}$. Can we say anything about the existence of $r \in \mathbb{P}, r \gt p_{\beta}$?

Comment: The statement "is it true that $\exists r\gt p_{\beta}, r\in\Bbb P$" taken by itself is true since there are an infinite number of primes...  Are there further conditions on $r$?

Comment: @abiessu: The last paragraph mentions the motivation for the question. Having exhausted trial division by primes up to $p_{\beta}$ we want to find an AP of the form $p_{\beta} + rt$ where $r \in \mathbb{P}$ satisfying $r > p_{\beta}$. The other constraint is that the AP contains either the smaller factor $p$ or the larger factor $q$ of the semiprime $n=pq$. The idea is to find a large $r$ so that we can find $p$ or $q$ in few steps by walking the AP.

Comment: Taking Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions, if we have $p_{\beta}\lt r$ are primes, then $(p_{\beta},r)=1$ and then $rt+p_{\beta}$ is an arithmetic progression in $t$ having an infinite number of primes as members...  We could easily build another sequence with $q$ in it, or even both $p,q$...

Comment: For the negative, note that it is quite easy to also choose $p\lt q\lt 2p$ primes such that no $r\gt p$ exists where both $p,q$ are members of an arithmetic progression on $r$...