# Constructing a subset of a set of arithmetic progressions that generate all primes in a range

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

I had asked a question recently ([A question on primes larger than a bound in an arithmetic progression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4543994/a-question-on-primes-larger-than-a-bound-in-an-arithmetic-progression)) on primes contained in an arithmetic progression with an initial term as a prime and common difference as a prime greater than the initial term.

This got me thinking about a more general question given below:

Let $p, q \in \mathbb{P}$, the set of primes, $M = \{m : m \in \mathbb{P}, p < m < q \}$ and $L = \{l : l \in \mathbb{P}, l < p\}$. Assume $M \ne \emptyset$.

Let $S(a, d)$ denote an arithmetic progression with initial term $a$ and common difference $d$.

Let $T = \{ S(m, l) : m \in M, l \in L\}$. **Can we construct $X$ a subset of $T$ that generates $M$?** i.e., if we generated the terms of the AP $S(m, l)$ for a subset of arithmetic progressions $X \subset T$ and collect the generated terms into a set $G$, is $M \subset G$?

The trivial case of the singleton set $X = \{ S(r, 2) \}$ i.e., the AP of odd numbers starting with an odd prime $r$, the minimal element of $M$ may be excluded as $M$ is obviously a subset of the generated terms of $S(r,2)$.

**Bonus question:** Assuming multiple subsets can generate $M$, is there a minimal subset based on $|X|$ and if there is one, how to construct it?

Comment: By your definition, $p\not\in M,$ so $S(p,2)$ doesn't work. Did you mean $\leq$ where you wrote $<$ in the definition of $M?$

Comment: You can likewise do $\{S(p_{+1},3), S(p_{-1},3)\}$ were $p_{i}$ is the smallest prime in $M$ with $p_i\equiv i\pmod{6}.$ Assuming $p>3.$

Comment: No. $S(p,2)$ generates odd numbers $\{p, p+2, p+4, ...\}$ and $M$ is a subset of this. since it contains primes between $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Your condition is $S(m.l)$ with $m\in M.$ $p\not\in M.$ So $S(p,2)$ is not allowed. $S(p',2)$ works, where $p'$ is the smallest element of $M,$ but $p'\neq p.$ @vvg

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: You are right. I probably abused the notation there reusing $p$. My intention is to exclude the trivial $S(r, 2)$ where $r$ is the smallest element of $M$.

Comment: In general, given any $r\in L,$ you do it in $r-1$ (or fewer) $S(m,l)$ with $l=r$ for all the them.